How to delete bytes in ghex instread of making them null bytes
I'm editing a jpg file. I am using ghex.
The problem I'm facing is I can make bytes 00(null byte)
But can't erase bytes. What to do?
how can I remove the 00 00 00 00 bytes

Shift + Arrow and pressing del doesn't work. It transforms the bytes to null bytes

Does this help?  https://help.gnome.org/users/ghex/3.18/ghex.html#ghex-edit-file

After opening a file in GHex hit the [T]-button in the right bottom corner of the GUI. Then use Shift+Arrow to select and press del to delete the bytes.

